# Bluemix Weather node of NodeRED is always throwing "call failed with error HTTP response"

Tags: node.js, nodes, ibm-cloud, weather, node-red

I am trying to test Insights for Weather service of Bluemix using NodeRED boilerplate. I created a simple nodeRED application and bound the "Insights for Weather" service with the app and so the corresponding node is available in nodeRED flow editor as well.

Attached first image which is a simple flow to test Weather node. It also has the stated error "Weather Insights service call failed with error HTTP response."  Whenever, I am triggering the flow by trigger node, stated error is appearing. Any clue to debug this issue ?

[image]

Second image is the Weather node configuration just for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Dhrubo,

It could be a problem with using credentials from a Bluemix region other than YP (US-South Production).  Credentials issued in one region are only valid for that region.

Node-red is using Insights for Weather for Bluemix in the US-South region so you must use credentials from that region. As you can see [on line 20](https://github.com/node-red/node-red-bluemix-nodes/blob/master/weather/weather_insights.js), the weather service host is hardcoded (twcservice.mybluemix.net) for the US-South region.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was because the location coordinates were not in the correct mode. Make sure you don't have any space between longitude and latitude.

Then try adding the Insights for weather service to your Bluemix application, then you will not need any username and password, because Node-RED will understand automatically that you have binded that service.